# Using image in xaml from Resources.resx

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my program, I have a resources file named "test" with image "test.png". I want to use it in a XAML file. But when program runs I don't see image.
My code:

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:ProjectB.Properties"
...
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static r:Resources.test}}" />
```

Build Action of the "test.png" image is set to Resource

EDIT:

I wanted to use an image in a resources file to be able to use different images in different globalizations (same as strings in resources file). I don't know it possible in the way I tried but I ended with adding images to normal folder in my project like answers below suggest, to resources file I added paths to image and XAML file looks like this:

```
<Image
Source="{Binding Source={x:Static r:Resources.test},
                 Converter={StaticResource StrToImgConv}}" />
```

Comment: Is your build action an `Embedded Resource` or just `Resource`?

Comment: Just Resource, but I tried Embedded Resource too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Resources.resx just add the test.png image to your project e.g in a 'Resources' folder and set the build action to `Embedded Resource` then you can use it in xaml code as shown below.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/test.png" />
```

if you used another folder structure in the Project don't forget to change it in the Source of the Image, for example, you want to keep images in 'Resources\images' so you should use the source as below.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/test.png" />
```

Comment: But I have two resources files because my app is in two languages. I wanted to add one image to Resources.resx and another with the same name but to Resources.pl-PL.resx. Is this possible to use images like strings in different globalizations?

Comment: @iknow you can use a globalization library or use a converter to build the image source uri

Answer (score 1):

A resources.resx file is completely unnecessary, as that is a file type used for WinForms, not WPF.

1. Delete your resources file (or just don't reference it as your source)
2. Keep your test.png file and keep its Build Action as Resource
3. Edit your xaml to this:

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:ProjectB.Properties"
...
<Image Source="Resources/test.png" />
```

Comment: But I have two resources files because my app is in two languages. I wanted to add one image to Resources.resx and another with the same name but to Resources.pl-PL.resx. Is this possible to use images like strings in different globalizations?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing without seeing more of your code, and what you are asking is outside the scope of your original question. You also don't state what your two languages are. Having said that, if your app replies on two different languages that have a shared resource, your first order of business is to find a base format that both languages can consume. I almost guarantee you that a resx file is not the solution you want.